# How to fix an error in SQL query in a Winforms application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, insert

I'm trying to insert data to a table called ansat (vagtplan). I'm currently writing a WinForms application which uses a SQL Server database, but I still get an error and I can't really see in the code where the error is.

I think, that it must be an error with the SQL query, because when I try to insert data to a table pressing a button, then I get following error message:

> Incorrect syntax near 'ansatID, Navn, Efternavn, Adresse, Email, Mobilnr'.

Desired result is a message box with 'Saved', which will confirm, that data are inserted to the table ansat(vagtplan). I have gone through the query many times, but I can't really see where the error is located, so my question is: where is the error located? Maybe should the query be formulated in another way? Here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
    {
        String ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Vagtplan;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        myconnection.Open();

        SqlCommand AddCommand = myconnection.CreateCommand();
        AddCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ansat(vagtplan) ([ansatID, Navn, Efternavn, Adresse, Email, Mobilnr]) VALUES (@ansatID, @Navn, @Efternavn, @Adresse, @Email, @Mobilnr)";

        AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ansatID", textBox8.Text);
        AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Navn", textBox1.Text);
        AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Efternavn", textBox2.Text);
        AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adresse", textBox3.Text);
        AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBox6.Text);
        AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobilnr", textBox7.Text);

        AddCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myconnection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved");
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the database name after the table name. _(vagtplan)_
And you don't put square brackets at the begin and and of the columns list. If you want to use them then put them around each column name _[ansatID], [Navn],..._

Comment: You should also dispose of the connection (as well as DBCommand objects) and avoid using `AddWithValue()`

Comment: `[ansatID, Navn, Efternavn, Adresse, Email, Mobilnr]` would mean a **single** column with the name `ansatID, Navn, Efternavn, Adresse, Email, Mobilnr`; i doubt that's what you're after. You quote individual columns, `[ansatID], [Navn],...`

Comment: Not sure what `INSERT INTO ansat(vagtplan) ([ansatID,...` is either, in honesty. Is `vagtplan` another column? If so, it should be in the same parenthesis as the other columns.

Comment: @Larnu ansatID, Navn, Efternavn, Adresse, Email, Mobilnr are each individual column and vagtplan is the name of the database and ansat is the name of the table, so that's why it is called ansat(vagtplan)

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain How to dispose the connection and avoid using AddWithValue()?

Comment: @PawełŻelazny that's what I assumed, but that's not what `[ansatID, Navn, Efternavn, Adresse, Email, Mobilnr]` means. That would be a single object (column) with a very lengthy (and rather silly) name.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1):

The insert statement is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ansat(ansatID, Navn, Efternavn, Adresse, Email, Mobilnr) 
VALUES(@ansatID, @Navn, @Efternavn, @Adresse, @Email, @Mobilnr)
```

No need to specify the database as its already mentioned in the connection string.

Comment: I have tried that , but I get following error message: Invalid object name  'ansat'.

Comment: So what *is* your table called @PawełŻelazny? You should be able to debug that problem. :)

Comment: If your table name is "ansat(vagtplan)" then try renaming it to "ansat". Special characters in table are considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following query:

```
INSERT INTO vagtplan.dbo.ansat ([ansatID], [Navn], [Efternavn], [Adresse], [Email], [Mobilnr]) values (@ansatID, @Navn, @Efternavn, @Adresse, @Email, @Mobilnr)
```

Comment: I have tried that, but I still get error message:Invalid object name 'ansat'.

Comment: Try this: INSERT INTO [vagtplan]..[ansat]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your command text `"INSERT INTO`**`ansat(vagtplan)`** `(`**`[ansatID, Navn, Efternavn, Adresse, Email, Mobilnr]`**`) values (@ansatID, @Navn, @Efternavn, @Adresse, @Email, @Mobilnr)";`

`INSERT` statement syntax is: `Insert into <tableName>(<column1>,<column2>) Values(<column1Value>,<column2Value>);`

1. Your `INSERT` statement's table name seems wrong. It seems `ansat` is schema name and `vagtplan` is table name, it should be like `ansat.vagtplan` or `[ansat].[vagtplan]`
2. Column names should be like `[column1],[column2]`. You have added all columns in a single `[]`; that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the table in SQL Server Management studio and then script, then INSERT into script. This will give you a SQL insert script for inserting into your table.  You can use this script as a basis to create your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all responses :) I havde figured it out and it works now, but another problem has occured. Now I'm trying to insert data to two tables related to each other through Foreign Key. Table dbo.Ansatte has a primary key called ansatID and table dbo.Login_data has a primary key called brugerID and foreign key AnsatID, which reference to primary key ansatID in table dbo.Ansatte. The primary key in both tables are inserted incrementally when the query s running. I have tried to set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON (in ms sql server management studio), but it doesn't help as I still get error message that IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. The problem is, that after running the query, foreign key AnsatID in table dbo.Login_data is still NULL despite the fact that foreign key AnsatID reference to primary key called ansatID in table dbo.Ansatte. Desired result is that foreign key AnsatID in table dbo.Login_data has the same value as primary key ansatID in table dbo.Ansatte. This also shown on the picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHqvP.png)

So, how to value from primary key into the foreign key?
Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            try
            {
                String ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Vagtplan;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                myconnection.Open();

                SqlCommand AddWorkerCommand = myconnection.CreateCommand();
                AddWorkerCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Ansatte ([Navn], [Efternavn], [Adresse], [Postnummer], [Bynavn], [Email], [Mobilnr]) VALUES ( @Navn, @Efternavn, @Adresse, @Postnummer, @Bynavn, @Email, @Mobilnr)";

                AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Navn", textBox1.Text);
                AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Efternavn", textBox2.Text);
                AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adresse", textBox3.Text);
                AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postnummer", textBox4.Text);
                AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bynavn", textBox5.Text);
                AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBox6.Text);
                AddWorkerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobilnr", textBox7.Text);
                AddWorkerCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlCommand AddUserCommand = myconnection.CreateCommand();
                AddUserCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Login_data ([Brugernavn], [Adgangskode], [Brugertype]) VALUES ( @Brugernavn, @Adgangskode, @Brugertype)";

                AddUserCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brugernavn", textBox10.Text);
                AddUserCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adgangskode", textBox9.Text);
                AddUserCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brugertype", textBox8.Text);
                AddUserCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                myconnection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Saved");
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
    }
```